# select and store core data relationships from tableview

Tags: user-interface, core-data, swift3, user-input, xcode8

This is my first time posting a question. I think in my initial post I didn't make it clear that what I really need to know is how to let the user assign the object to the other object it's related to. Currently variations of this

```
contract.wageClass = wageClassIDLabel.text
```

give variations of the error "cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSSet'.

I have two core data entities, Contract and WageClass. Both relationships are to-many (Contracts can have many wage classes, wage classes can belong to more than one contract). I've got no problem allowing the user to add to the store of wage classes and contracts, I just can't figure out how to allow the user to select the actual associated data.

Note: I used editor -> Create NSMangedObject SubClass rather than Codegen so I could see and edit the classes.

This is the view controller where the user enters the data to create a wage class:

```
import UIKit

class AddWCViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfWorkersField: UITextField!


    @IBOutlet weak var wagePerHourField: UITextField!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func submitButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {



        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

        let wageClass = WageClass(context: context)

        wageClass.name = nameField.text!
        wageClass.numberOfWorkers = (numberOfWorkersField.text! as NSString).doubleValue
        let numWorkers = wageClass.numberOfWorkers
        wageClass.wagesPerHour = (wagePerHourField.text! as NSString).doubleValue
        let classPerHour = wageClass.wagesPerHour
        wageClass.classTotalWagesPerHour = numWorkers * classPerHour






        //Save it

        (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)



    }
}
```

I know I need to use the class extension addToContract but how do I let the user select the contract through the UI? And how do I let the user select more than one contract?

**update**:

I added a tableview and set it to allow for multiple selections in editing. Now I'm looking for a way to save the selections.

```
import UIKit

class SelectWCTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var selectTableView: UITableView!



    var wageClasses: [WageClass] = []






    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        selectTableView.dataSource = self
        selectTableView.delegate = self
         selectTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
         selectTableView.setEditing(true, animated: false)



    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //get data from Core Data
        getData()



        //reload tableview

        selectTableView.reloadData()

    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return wageClasses.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ElementCell")

        let wageClass = wageClasses[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(wageClass.name!)"

        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(wageClass.numberOfWorkers) workers @\(wageClass.wagesPerHour)/per hour =\(wageClass.classTotalWagesPerHour) total paid"

        return cell
    }



    func getData() {
        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
        do {
            wageClasses = try context.fetch(WageClass.fetchRequest())



            //            var totalWagesPaidPerClass = 0
            //            for wageClass in wageClasses {
            //                let people = wageClass.valueForKey("numberOfWorkers") as! Int
            //                let hours = wageClass.valueForKey("wagePerHour") as! Int
            //                totalWagesPaidPerClass += people * hours
            //            }



        }
        catch {
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you built the relationships between the 2 entities in the core data model ?

If not follow this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/HowManagedObjectsarerelated.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH17-SW16) to create the relationships between the 2 entities. That way you would be able to access the `wageClass.contracts` and `contracts.wageClasses`.

Core data doesn't build the UI for you. Core data is used only for data persistence. You have to build the UI yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is about how to let the user select the contract through the UI.

Comment: Are you asking what the UI should look like ? Or how the UI should be implemented ?

Comment: How the UI should be implemented. UIPickerView? How do you select more than one at a time?